# Create a product list with paging in Umbraco 7.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, umbraco, umbraco7

I want to create a product list with paging shown as below

[image]

I have searched on the Jquery or javascript to achieve this and found that we can use [JSPages](https://github.com/luis-almeida/jPages/tree/master/js). But how do i integrate this in Umbraco?

For each category, there are many products. So for that also, i need to create a page with paging. So When user click in Category A, it should redirect to another page (which is Product list page) with the same functionality.

Also, where do i mention that Product A, Product B are from Category A.

So how do i achieve this ?

Comment: As far as I am aware of, there is no out of the box solution for Umbraco, and in most cases with MVC, you have the html helper. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880179/1435590).

Comment: I think it's important to ask how many products you actually have. If you have a lot of products under a certain category, you'd want to narrow down the number of items prior to returning to a front end paging solution.

It's almost important to note that what you're asking is very open ended. Have you done any querying in Umbraco?